# pyautogui.locateOnScreen() for multiple images?

Tags: python, pyautogui

How would you do `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` for multiple images a **bunch** of images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import os
import pyautogui as py


image_list = []

# Get list of all files in current directory
directory = os.listdir()

# Find files that end with .png or .jpg and add to image_list
for file in directory:
    if file.endswith('.png') or file.endswith('.jpg'):
        image_list.append(file)

# Loop through list to find all the images
for image in image_list:
    print(image)
    print(py.locateOnScreen(image))
```

This question is similar to another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044732/how-to-use-pyautogui-for-images), I posted the same answer in both places.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_coordinates(images):
    # Capture your screen only once.
    haystack = pyautogui.screenshot()
    
    # Loop through multiple images
    for needle in images:

        # Get coordinates of image within screen capture
        return pyautogui.locate(needle, haystack)
        
    print("Images not found!")
```

Use the screenshot func to capture your screen and then loop through the different images to find a match.

To optimize see [optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42976064/12406791)